# How to use the Rotativa.aspnetcore package in Linux Ubuntu OS (asp.net Core 2.1)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

Using the Rotativa.aspnetcore package in Ubuntu doesn't know what's wrong?

1. I use the Visual Studio 2017 MVC Default Template.
2. Using nuget Rotativa.aspnetcore (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa.AspNetCore/)

Install-Package Rotativa.AspNetCore -Version 1.1.1

3. Perform sudo apt-get install Xvfb libfontconfig wkhtmltopdf in Linux Ubuntu OS. wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage copy it to Web MVC project wwwroot/Rotativa.
4. According to Rotativa.aspnetcore Git (https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore) file Needs configuration settings
   configuration done in Startup.cs:

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       ...

       app.UseHttpsRedirection();
       app.UseStaticFiles();
       app.UseCookiePolicy();

       app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Faceapirequestrecords}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
       });

       RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env, "/usr/bin");
   }
   ```
5. HomeController program code :

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public IActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }

       public IActionResult DemoViewAsPDF()
       {
           return new ViewAsPdf("Index");
       }
   }
   ```
6. Deploy and execute MVC applications.
   URL : http://localhost:5000/Home/DemoViewAsPDF

   ## Error Message:

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
>             Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
>
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
>             An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.Exception: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
>
> at Rotativa.AspNetCore.WkhtmlDriver.Convert(String wkhtmlPath, String switches, String html, String wkhtmlExe)
>      at Rotativa.AspNetCore.WkhtmltopdfDriver.ConvertHtml(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches, String html)
>      at Rotativa.AspNetCore.ViewAsPdf.CallTheDriver(ActionContext context)
>      at Rotativa.AspNetCore.AsResultBase.BuildFile(ActionContext context)
>      at Rotativa.AspNetCore.AsResultBase.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
>   context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult
>   result)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsyncTFilter,TFilterAsync
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext
>   context)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

Answer (score -3):

In advance: I didn't test it.

You are trying to call http://localhost:5000/Home/DemoViewAsPDF with port 5000. Rotativa tries to redirect to http***s***://localhost:5000/Home/DemoViewAsPDF. The Port for https is different. Therefore you don't get a result.

Try to use https from the start. This might solve your problem.

You can test if Rotativa works as intended by accessing the program via the command prompt:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe www.samplewebsite.com  outputfolder+filename+extension
```